# Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. Gradle

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to set up my first gradle project in eclipse but im having problem with building gradle. I' ve copied build.gradle from spring.io but still it wont build properly. I get  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. My build.gradle file looks like this

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
// tag::jetty[]
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
// end::jetty[]
// tag::actuator[]
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
// end::actuator[]
testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Comment: What is the full output? Use "-s" argument to the build command please.

Comment: @MartinLinha Error details http://pastebin.com/PgAmm0Sx

Answer (score 0):

Your build cannot be compiled, as stated

`Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

check the code and find what causes it to not to build. Try to run the command with `-s -i` options to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change the javahome variable to point to the proper directory, i.e. to your jdk home directory.

In Eclipse you can change the path in a run configuration under Java Home, for example to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4`.
Then run the configuration as `clean` and `assemble`.

[image: Eclipse]