# IntelliJ Using Wrong JDK - Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > invalid source release: 11

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-11

My project runs on the command line but fails to run in IntelliJ.  I've tried all of the solutions in the following questions:

- [Error: Java: invalid target release: 11 - IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54137286/715608)
- [Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42529580/715608)
- [Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > invalid source release: 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450923/715608)

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### However I did notice that Gradle is compiling the project with the wrong JDK

Does anyone know why InteliJ is not using the JDK I defined?

[image]

#### I also tried overriding JAVA_HOME

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Configure IntelliJ IDEA Gradle JDK: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Gradle JVM.

[image: Gradle JVM]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this worked for me:

1. Close IntelliJ
2. On the command line, run `sdk default java 11.0.11.9.1-amzn`
3. Restart IntelliJ
4. Rerun the app within IntelliJ

[image]

#### Note:

I'm still interested to know how to override the SDKMAN setting within IntelliJ.  If anyone knows, please adda comment or answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

USE SDKMAN to install the java versions . configure the installed sdks into IntelliJ and use the appropriate one for the project